# PhpMyAdmin 4.6.2 upgrade not working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have just installed an update for PhpMyAdmin.  Old version was 4.5.1.  Upgrade to version 4.6.2 .  My current version of PHP is 5.5.36 .

I have followed all the installation / upgrade documentation provided on the phpmyadmin site.  I have copied over all new update files into a new fresh directory.  I have copied over my config.inc.php file to the main root phpmyadmin dir as well as created a config dir with the same file in it.

When I attempt to login I receive the following error:

```
Error

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET lc_messages = 'en_US';

MySQL said: Documentation
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL version is too old.  Prior to v5.5 lc_messages [was not available](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html).  Try upgrading the MySQL server.

Comment: It was working with PhpMyAdmin version 4.5.1 which is my current installation.

Comment: What version is the *database server* (mysqld)?